# What Mongo GUI tools can I use to connect to my deployed Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

Tools like MongoLab remote connection and RockMongo require a permanent URL, so the URLs generated by "meteor mongo --url" that are only valid for 1 minute don't work for long.

Comment: Found https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac, which seems to work pretty well. It's still a pity that you can't use tools like MongoLab remote connection and RockMongo.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a mac I would recommend that fononauts build of MongoHub you put up, the ordinary Mongohub is quite buggy & on Windows use MongoVue which is perhaps the best one i've used of all.